# Matching on enum : First arm unexpectedly always matching

Tags: rust, enums, pattern-matching

I have a wierdest case yet on my hands. I have an enum that I convert to a string. The enum provided is eg. Green so the string returned from the match is "text-success". Simple right? Turns out that the string returned is always "" regardless of how I obtain it. This makes no sense to me. Please help!

```
fn bootstrap_table_color (e: Color) -> String {
    let s: String = match &e {
        White => "".to_string(),
        Blue => String::from("table-info"),
        Green => "table-success".to_string(),
        Yellow => "table-warning".to_string(),
        Red => "table-danger".to_string(),
    };
    println!("bootstrap_table_color ({:?}) -> {:?}", e, s);
    return s;
}

bootstrap_table_color (Blue) -> ""
bootstrap_table_color (Green) -> ""
```

Comment: This is a common error, but one that is caught by compiler warnings extremely effectively. If you turned them off, consider turning them on, and actually going through them - it will make your experience with Rust much more pleasant.

Comment: I agree. I was focused on adding the next feature so much and left the warnings for later. I do this often because there is plenty of unused variables and functions when I start implementing. This was a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because all possible values match the `White` variable arm.

You could see it by doing

```
let s: String = match &e {
    White => format!("White={:?}", White),
}
```

The clean solution is to prefix arm values with your enum name:

```
let s = match &e {
    Color::White => "".to_string(),
    Color::Blue => String::from("table-info"),
    Color::Green => "table-success".to_string(),
    Color::Yellow => "table-warning".to_string(),
    Color::Red => "table-danger".to_string(),
};
```

Another solution would be to do a `use Color::*;` but you would be vulnerable to typos or changes.

Comment: The compiler generates literally pages of warning pointing it out tho: unreachable pattern warnings, [pattern with name of variant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0170), unused value, local variable name formatting warning, ... These 11 lines generate 19 different warnings, you'd think that would be noticeable.

Comment: You are both right. Big kudos for solving this for me!